# Finding the pre-image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $T$, A linear transformation such that:

$$T\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   x_1  \\
   x_2  \\
   x_3
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2x_1 - x_2 + 5x_3  \\
   - 4x_1 + 2x_2 - 10x_3
\end{array} \right]$$

What is the pre-image for 
$T^{ - 1}\left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   4 \\
   - 8
\end{array} \right]$?

After row reduction we have:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & - \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{2} & 2  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]$$

Obviously, there are infinitely many solutions, but how to represent it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

---

The offered book's solution is:

$$T^{ - 1} \left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   4  \\
   - 8
\end{array} \right] = \left\{ \left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2  \\
   0  \\
   0
\end{array} \right] + x_2 \left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {1/2}  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{array} \right] + {x_3}\left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   -5/2  \\
   0  \\
   1
\end{array} \right] \mid x_{2,} x_3 \in F \right\}$$

Can you help me interpret it?

EDIT2:

---

Never mind, Got it. it's the same representation as offered here.

Comment: You have a map from R^3 to R^2. This shouldn't have 4 columns.

Comment: it's in the form of $Ax = b$, where the fourth row is $b$. I think it's fine.

Comment: {x_{2,}}{x_3} instead of x_{2,} x_3 and a zillion other things like that.  All those tons of extra curly braces can make editing more difficult. I deleted them.  Maybe I missed some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce free parameters s and t. 
$$
(x_1,x_2, x_3) = (2+s/2-5t/2,s,t)
$$

Comment: Firstly, Thanks. Can you have a look at my edit please?