# Compute preimage of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working on an assignment and I've pored over my lecture notes, but I can't find anything about this.

I'm told to define the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by 
$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}\right)= \begin{bmatrix}
2x_1-x_2+5x_3\\
-4x_1+2x_2-10x_3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then I'm asked to compute the preimage of $T^{-1} \left(\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}\right)$, and find a basis for the kernel of $T$ and asked whether $T$ is injective.

Based on this question, [Finding the pre-image of a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670986/finding-the-pre-image-of-a-linear-transformationm), which is very similar, do I simply row reduce $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 5 & 2\\
-4& 2 & -10 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}?$$

If so, that system is inconsistent.  So is there no preimage?

Comment: yes and yes. {}{}

Comment: Sure looks that way.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks, @qbert and @amd!  :)

Comment: The correct spelling is "pore over", by the way.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're absolutely right, how embarrassing!